# Saving my Word documents online

Tags: online-storage, office-365, microsoft-word

I can't quite believe this isn't possible, though I fear it may not be.

I have Windows 7, Office 2010 (or whatever the latest version is) and a Windows Live account.

I want to write a document in Word on my desktop and save it straight to Windows Live.  This should be easy. Is it?  Does Microsoft support this? It seems like a simple request in 2011.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/

> Create a great looking document in Office and then switch easily from working on it on your PC or in the browser

[Upload documents to use in Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/upload-documents-to-use-in-office-web-apps-HA010389582.aspx)

> If you have Microsoft Office 2010 you can upload documents directly to your Windows Live SkyDrive from Excel, OneNote, PowerPoint, and Word. On the **Save & Send tab** in Backstage view, click **Save to Web**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks just what I wanted, but its a bit slow and not very well integrated.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Live):

> Office Live Workspace is currently not
>   supported on Office 2010. In May 2010,
>   it was announced that Office Live
>   Workspace customers would be moved to
>   Microsoft's [SkyDrive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SkyDrive) service, which
>   offers 25GB of storage and the ability
>   to view and edit documents through
>   [Office Web Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Apps).

See also:

> [Office Live Workspace team blog: Your Office Live Workspace is soon upgrading to Windows Live SkyDrive](http://ask.officelive.com/workspace/blogs/workspace_team/archive/2010/05/12/your-office-live-workspace-is-soon-upgrading-to-windows-live-skydrive.aspx)